# Rails & Rolify: Add default role on creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, roles

Currently I'm using **Rolify & CanCan** to manage roles and abilities in my Rails 3 app. My question is: How can I get a user to have a role by default on creation? for example, if I have a "user" role, ¿How can I make all the users that register in my app have a **user** Role by default? My **Ability.rb** has this code:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.has_role? :user
      can :update, User, :id => user.id
    end
  end
end
```

My **User Model** has this one:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  authenticates_with_sorcery!
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :username
  validates_uniqueness_of :username
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
end
```

The **Role Model** This One:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true
end
```

And From the **UsersController** we have:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  if @user.save
    redirect_to users_path, :notice => "Tu usuario se ha guardado"
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

Finally the **Rolify Migration** is this one:

```
class RolifyCreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:roles) do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :resource, :polymorphic => true

      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table(:users_roles, :id => false) do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :role
    end

    add_index(:roles, :name)
    add_index(:roles, [ :name, :resource_type, :resource_id ])
    add_index(:users_roles, [ :user_id, :role_id ])
  end
end
```

Now, I can assign roles manually from the **rails console** by using:

```
1 User.all
2 User.find(id)
3 User.add_role(:role)
```

But how can I assign automatically a default role when *every user* it's created?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget it, Just had to add:

```
@user.add_role(:user)
```

in my create action right after the `@user = User.new(params[:user])` line.

Figured it out by myself... I'm still learning :)

Thanks!

Comment: You're doing this in the controller which is the wrong place to be doing it. Logic like this should go in the model. The saying is "skinny controllers, fat models". Doing this in the model will also let you do unit tests rather than controller tests.

Comment: Dty has a point. You want it to be DRY. Any controller/action that creates a user would have to have this line of code.
By putting it in the model with after_create callback, you got it DRY.

Comment: Why don't put it in a migration? Something like:
def change
    change_column :users, :role, :integer, :default => 'user'
end

Then when an user is created using devise, by default it becomes the role 'user'.

Answer (score 23):

You can use an [active record callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks) to assign the role after the user is created. Something like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :assign_default_role

  def assign_default_role
    add_role(:role)
  end
end
```

Note that there's also an `after_save` callback but it's called EVERY time the user is saved. So if you edit the user and save it would try to add the role again. That's why I'm using the `after_create` callback instead.

Comment: This is a Good solution too! ;)

Comment: Brilliant! Saved me much grief.

Comment: you'd better check if a role is assigned before `add_role`

Comment: @CamSong but this is an after_create callback, so no need to check.

Answer (score 7):

You'd better check if a role is assigned before add_role. so I prefer:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :assign_default_role

  def assign_default_role
    add_role(:normal) if self.roles.blank?
  end
end
```

Comment: This is after_create, shouldn't have any other roles.

Answer (score 2):

```
after_create :default_role

private
  def default_role
    self.roles << Role.find_by_name("user")
    self.save
  end
```